# Mobile traffic intercept via charles very cumbersome through wifi proxy setting, any better solution

Tags: testing, mobile, charles-proxy

Each time setting proxy in wifi settings in mobile is very cumbersome and many times it not works very well. Need to restart charles, disconnect wifi and connect again.

Any good and reliable approach?

I tried by setting proxy in wifi and configuring port of charles in proxy port.

Comment: Not with Charles. [Mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org) supports a Wireguard mode which means you can enable/disable redirection on your smartphone using the official Wireguard app: just enable/disable the Mitmproxy VPN target.